# ionic ion-header-bar style is broken on ios

Tags: android, ios, css, ionic-framework

I use the ionic framework to build applications on iOS and android.
The problem is that the ion-header-bar style that is normally implemented on Android is awfully broken on iOS.
Below is a screenshot of the mobile phone.

{left: ios, right: android}

[image]

Below is the main page debugged in Safari.

The blue shaded area is the header-bar area.

[image]

I wonder if there are options that I have to specify for ios separately. or override style.

Comment: Are you solved your issue?

Comment: @shahnilay86 I've overridden the style code as shown below in my answer. Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: have you try my code? i.e. `<ion-header>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by overriding the sass file.
The style code added to the ionic.app.sass file is shown below.

```
.platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .bar-header:not(.bar-subheader)
  height: 84px
  .platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .bar-header:not(.bar-subheader).item-input-inset .item-input-wrapper
    margin-top: 19px !important
  .platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .bar-header:not(.bar-subheader) > *
    margin-top: 20px

.platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .has-header,
.platform-ios.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .bar-subheader
  top: 84px
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `<ion-header>` instead of `<ion-header-bar>`. Also close the same tag in your html file.

In my project it will working fine with `<ion-header>`.

**Suggestion for write the tag :-**

When you will go for write a tag `<ion-header>` at that time it can be possible framework will not give you a suggestion for this tag. Then also you can write and try with given tag.

Hopy it will work for you.